# How can I sync MySQL database (or my website reservations) via channel manager without extra providers?

Tags: php, mysql, api, booking.com-api

I have a website that makes hotel reservations via a form. For now, I save the data to MySQL database.

Do I need a channel manager for that?
How can I make my own channel manager without extra providers to sync my data with booking.com?

Also, I already own a slim-api to retrieve the data from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you have to register as affiliate partner with booking.com
2. then you can request for developer page access
3. once you get the access for developer page, you can get an API Key and you can see the full XML API documentation.
4. Then you can start developing 2 way request and responses according to their document.

Comment: I said in the topic "without extra providers".I don't wanna pay for affiliate partnership.That's the only way?

Comment: There are no payment to become as an Affiliate. Its all about satisfying OTA's requirement, where they will evaluate your application, schema, consistancy to approve you as an Affiliate.

Comment: They had asked for money at phone as i remember but i will try this again.So they will give me their channel manager to host on my own server right? Or need to make my own api based on their documentation?

Comment: Update your answer please with how to make 2 way xml request on unix if you know,all docs are welcome,thanks.

Comment: requests are independent of operating system.

Comment: If you are really contact the OTA (Booking.com / expedia), they will first evaluate you for providing their API.
First send your expression of interest to, connectivity@booking.com